# TFS 2010 mapping dependent files for builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am pretty new to TFS and Build configuration tasks so forgive me if this problem has a simple answer.

I have a team project that is sort of a common library(CL) that contains dlls and apis that I commonly use throughout my projects. All my other projects reference files directly from the mapped folder for the CL on my dev machine.

I am trying to set up a build definition for Project A(Build server is on a different machine). I want always ensure that the CL is the latest before each build so is it possible to have the build definition pull the latest files first? The only other alternative is to start including the CL in of every project directly.

I tried adding a working folder for the CL, but it does not seem to get the files before it attempts to build project A. And then after when I try to rebuild after the failure, I receive a error saying that the CL working folder "is already mapped in workspace".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mapping in the sources, why not build the common library, deploy it to a common location, and have all the projects that use it reference it at the common location?

In addition to simply making more sense (it should be common binary, not common source), this greatly improves Continuous Integration builds. If several builds map the same source into their workspace, then when the common source is changed, *all* of those CI builds will be kicked off.

Comment: John, I have 2 TFS Projects (Domain and Web) and the way I see it you recommend that (in my case) I need to let the Domain build first to a common location (C:\Dependencies\) and then have the web include that dll? That means that the location MUST be the same on my local machine as on the TFS build server? Any way for me to have them different? I do a Web Transform for web.config but have no idea how to do this. How do I get TFS to build 2 projects from different TFS collections, one after the other? And how do I check out the dll on the server so that the build includes the new one? Thanks

Comment: @Jack, if they're in the same solution, then this isn't an issue. Simply have the Web project reference the Domain project. The original question involved multiple solutions so needed a different solution. If you need more information, then please ask a new question assuming your question hasn't already been asked.